# Return newly updated document after update in Firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I currently have firebase initialized on the front end of a react application.  Within the application, I am updating the user document using the following code:

```
  const handleProfileUpdate = async () => {
    const sourceRef = firestore()
      .collection('users')
      .where('userId', '==', state.currentUser.userId)
    sourceRef
      .get()
      .then(async snapshot => {
        if (snapshot.empty) {
          console.log('user not found')
        } else {
          snapshot.forEach(async doc => {
            await doc.ref.update({ firstName: detailsToUpdate })
            console.log(doc)
          })
        }
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error.code))
  }
```

The document is successfully updated, but I would like to return a reference to the updated document as opposed to having to query the user document again.  Does .update() return a reference to the updated document or is there another way I should go about this?

Comment: You already have that reference in `doc.ref`.

Comment: ahh okay wasn't sure if i could get the reference to the document.  thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firestore doesn't have a way to get the updated values of a document from the result of a write method(add, set, update, delete). To get the new values, you have to call `doc.ref.get()`, thereby making a new read to the firestore servers.